# I already selected ESP32 wrover module but still it's showing error "Pleas select the corresponding module"

Tags: arduino, esp32

I was compiling the code of arduino_TinyGSM but the following error occur, I don't know what to do.
[image]

Here is code link:https://github.com/Xinyuan-LilyGO/LilyGo-T-Call-SIM800/tree/master/examples/Arduino_TinyGSM

Answer (score 0):

This error doesn't refer to your ESP board, but rather your SIM800 module. If you look at example sketches in the , e.g. [Arduino_SMS.ino](https://github.com/Xinyuan-LilyGO/LilyGo-T-Call-SIM800/blob/aa5f811b0a3b026f5a9697d61750dccc1367797a/examples/Arduino_SMS/Arduino_SMS.ino), then you see some preprocessor definition which selects the SIM800 hardware and firmware combination used. You need to do the same.

Comment: Yes I have esp32 sim800l module but I didn't catch exactly what I need to do. By the way I bought this module yesterday, So I really don't know what error is about.

Comment: According to the [file which probably generates this error](https://github.com/Xinyuan-LilyGO/LilyGo-T-Call-SIM800/blob/master/examples/Arduino_AT_Debug/utilities.h) you need to select the specific model and firmware version in your SIM800 module by #defining one of the preprocessor constants listed there - `SIM800L_IP5306_VERSION_20190610`, etc. How you are supposed to figure that information out is beyond me. Maybe it's written on the label. If not, some AT command will tell you.

Comment: Hey MAN, got it finally know to counter that error,Thanks a lot MAN